# What device manufacturers have their own Java ME API's

Tags: api, windows-mobile, java-me

I know that BlackBerry and Nokia provide their own API's that go above and beyond what is specified in MIDP, CLDC, or any of the JSRs for Java ME.

I am looking at a few other platforms for Java ME development and needed to know:

Do Windows Mobile, LG, Samsung, ZTE, or Huawei provide their own API's for Java ME development?

**Edit**: It is difficult to choose an accepted answer because all of the answers contain useful data. I am giving it to Wonil for pointing out the Sprint APIs which I would have never, ever found.

Thanks Everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [LGE Java Platform](http://developer.lgmobile.com/lge.mdn.tnd.RetrieveTopicSub.dev?returnName=&resourceNo=LGSpecificFeatures&isFromAdmin=N&menuClassCd=&objectType=&prevUrl=%2Flge.mdn.tec.RetrieveTechInfo.dev%3FresourceNo%3DIntroductiontoLGJavaPlatform&overallRating=0) specific features. Also, you can find [Sprint Extension API](http://developer.sprint.com/getDocument.do?docId=98390) for Java ME. This is not OEM specific but, carrier specific.

Answer (score 1):

Some Samsung devices support the [Samsung API](http://www.j2megame.org/j2meapi/Samsung_API_1_0/index.html).  This seems to vary amongst devices though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 3 Hong Kong CFMWriter API was implemented on at least one Huawei handset and one LG handset.

It is used to encrypt data written on the handset file system.

Several Samsung handsets use the Nokia Series60 platform so they would contain a lot of Nokia-specific enhancements.

Sony Ericsson also has its own set of APIs.

Comment: Can you post a link to CFMWriter documentation?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't know what kind of legal access restriction covers it.

Comment: I can't seem to find it on google. Can you provide any link which will point me to where I can find it? I can sign up myself if I have to.

Comment: You probably need to contact 3hongkong directly.